# Can't seem to center two floated tags

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to float two items within a div next to each, an `<img>` and an `<h1>`. I'm trying `inline-block` but it doesn't seem to work. I want the `<img>` and `<h1>` to be centered within its div. Also, if it can be done, I want the `<h1>` to be even with the center of the `<img>` on the left. Equal distance from the top as from the below.

```css
body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
  font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;
  margin: 0;
}

.yaboi,
.hd2 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.plswork {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* display:inline-block; */
}

.yaboi .plswork h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.yaboi .plswork img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
  <div class="yaboi">
    <div class="plswork">
      <img src="188104.jpg" alt="PC with keyboard and mouse" />
      <h1>Falcon Tech</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hd2">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Since you mentioned that you are attempting to achieve this using inline-block elements I will show how to do that first:

```
.plswork {
    text-align: center;
}
.plswork img,
.plswork h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<div class="plswork">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x10">
    <h1>Falcon Tech</h1>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4s4Lmhnn/

Floats are not typically suitable for horizontal centering, so you will notice that my solution does not make use of floats.

It is unclear from your question whether you want horizontal or vertical centering *within the containing element* . I have assumed that you only want horizontal centering, though my solution does align the `img` and `h1` vertically relative to one another.

If, instead, you need both elements to be vertically centered inside a container of unknown height then flexbox is a good option:

```
.plswork {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3hxb2xo3/2/

Comment: Holy moly it worked, thank you! I know know of the vertical-align tag, thanks again.